# Find value in dictionary which is inside another dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary variable which looks like this -

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>> newIds;
```

I want to search for the value of internal dictionary using keys I have.
Let's assume key for outer dictionary is **NAME**(string) and key for inner dictionary is **1**(int). I want to search the value of inner dictionary using these keys. 
How can I do that? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: So let me see if I understand. You want something like this:
`int value = newIds[strKey][intKey]`

Comment: It will be helpful if you put some sample data in your question. Which data will be in Dictionary?

Comment: @Agustin0987 Its so simple! thank you for ur help!

Comment: @GaurangDave in dictionary signature u can see data type. I wanted to search the value(int) of innner dictionary. Thanks for ur reply. Cheers!

Comment: @Md.ParwezAkhtar Now think about the code if either the name or the int or both don't exist in the dictionary...

Comment: @MineR I didnt think about it? Can I have a check for the keys if they are available? Sorry to ask silly questions..I am very new in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do something like:

```
bool found = TryGet(newIds, "Name", 1, out int result);

public bool TryGet(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>> dicts, string name, int num, out int val)
{
    val = -1;
    if (dicts.TryGetValue(name, out Dictionary<int, int> dict))
    {
        if (dict.TryGetValue(num, out int res))
        {
            val = res;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I am just recieving some data from server which is to be framed in the above manner.I have no control on the response type. That'swhy using dictionary inside dictionary. Thanks for ur reply!